# LINQ Group By with subquery

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to make a query on LINQ using a GroupBy, where on the Select statement I try to make some kind of subquery. The idea is that I have 7 days to look for, I need to get the average value of these last 7 days but also the current value for the current day. So I have tried the following code:

```
        var oDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var startDate = oDate.AddWorkingDays(-7);
        var endDate = oDate.AddWorkingDays(-1);

        var races = RaceTimes.Where(
            x =>
                x.ODate >= startDate && x.ODate <= oDate && x.Status == "Finished")
            .GroupBy(x => x.Athletes.Name).Select(x => new 
            {
                Name = x.Key,
                Description = "Just a Random Description for now",
                ODate = oDate,
                SevenDaysAvg = (int?)x.Where(y => y.ODate >= startDate && y.ODate <= endDate).Average(y => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", y.StartTime, y.EndTime)),
                RaceTime = (int?)x.Where(y => y.ODate == oDate).Average(y => SqlFunctions.DateDiff("s", y.StartTime, y.EndTime))
            }).ToList().Where(x => x.RaceTime!= null).ToList();
```

The SevenDaysAvg (average) works fine, it returns me the average of the last 7 days races. However, Latency is always returning me null.

I am trying to make the translation of my query from SQL, which works fine:

```
...
AVG(case when h.ODate BETWEEN '20140219' AND '20140227' then DATEDIFF(SECOND, h.StartTime, h.EndTime)  else null end) AS SevenDaysAvg,
AVG(case when h.ODate = '20140227' then DATEDIFF(SECOND, h.StartTime, h.EndTime) else null end) AS RaceTime,
...
```

So what am I doing wrong in my LINQ query? This what I am doing is not possible? I've also tried another aproach. First calculate all averages, and then in the main query have something like:

```
SevenDaysAvg = averages.Where(y => y.Name== x.Athletes.Name).Select(y => y.SevenDaysAvg).FirstOrDefault()
```

Once again, this approach didnt work, it keeps giving me empty results. Whats wrong here?

Comment: You don't have Latency property in Select predicate at all. I believe you forget to copy it

Comment: `.Where(x => x.Latency != null)` - I don't see Latency in your projection, it wouldn't compile?

Comment: Just edited. It was a copy paste mistake. Sorry

Comment: Anyway, it returns empty result set everytime so I dont know how to perform sth like this...

Comment: I mean, i tried two different solutions, as I presented, and both return empty result sets. Why cant he infere this on the query time?

Comment: `var oDate = DateTime.UtcNow`, then `x.Where(y => y.ODate == oDate)` means that your trying to find **Date** and **Time** parts (and not only Date), which won't exist in database - or is it another copy/paste issue?

Comment: You're absolutely right. Let me fix this to see what I get